# Calculating the integral closure (normalizatrion) of a quotient over a polynomial ring in three variables.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/((x+a)^2-z(y+z^b)^2)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume that $A$ is an integral domain (this is easy to show, you can just use Generalised Eisenstein over $\mathbb{Q}[y,z][x+a]$ with prime ideal $(z)$ I think). The question is to compute the integral closure of $A$.
My initial guess was to find an integral element say $t$ not in $A$ and adjoin to find $A[t]$ and hopefully this would be my integral closure. Letting $t=\frac{x+a}{y+z^b}$ seems to be the obvious choice, and belongs to $Frac(A)$.

My attempt: Shift the variables of $A$ to be over $u,v,z$ where $u=x+a$, $v=y+z^b$ (First question, *why* can I so this? I haven't found a reason I trust enough, though I'm sure its just isomorphisms that allow me to do this? Is there a way to do this without shifting?).

Then I have the string of isomorphisms as below:
\begin{align*}
    A[t] \cong A\left[\frac{u}{v}\right] &\cong \left(\mathbb{Q}[u, v, z] /\left(u^{2}-z v^{2}\right)\right)\left[\frac{u}{v}\right]\\
    &\cong \mathbb{Q}\left[u, v, \frac{u^2}{v^2}\right]\left[\frac{u}{v}\right]\\
    &\cong \mathbb{Q}\left[v,\frac{u}{v} \right]
\end{align*}
Now clearly $A[t]$ is integrally closed if you note that $v, u/v$ is independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus we have it is isomorphic to the UFD $\mathbb{Q}\left[v,\frac{u}{v} \right]$. My second question, is why exactly is this $A[t]$ the integral closure? Is it becasue $A[t]$ is contained in the integral closure of $A$ or is it other way around, i.e. it contains it. And why? It doesn't seem obvious to me.
Lastly, is there an easier/simpler way to tackle this? My course is working through Atiyah and MacDonald's *Commutative Algebra*.
(I haven't had the most solid basis for ring theory, so even simple explanations are helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the variables in such a way by what is called the *universal property of polynomial rings*: a ring homomorphism from a polynomial ring $R[X_i:i\in I]$ is completely determined on $R$ and $X_i$.

We have two morphisms $\Psi, \Phi$ between polynomial rings $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z] \rightleftarrows \mathbb{Q}[u,v,w]$ such that
$$\Psi(x)=u-a, \Psi(y)=v-w^b, \Psi(z)=w,$$
$$\Phi(u)=x-a, \Phi(v)=y+z^b, \Phi(w)=z.$$
Since $\Psi\circ\Phi$ and $\Phi\circ\Psi$ map indeterminates to themselves, they must be identity, i.e. $\Psi$ is an isomorphism. It follows that $\Psi$ maps the ideal $((x+a)^2-z(y+z^b)^2)$ to $(u^2-v^2w)$ and by quotienting we get $A\simeq \mathbb{Q}[u,v,w]/(u^2-v^2w)=\mathbb{Q}[u,v,u^2/v^2]$. We can see that $B=\mathbb{Q}[u,u/v]$ is integral over $A$ since it is obtained by adjoining an integral element $\in \operatorname{Frac}A$ so that $B 
$ is contained in the integral closure, and it is integrally closed since it is UFD. As in the case of fields, if we have a tower of ring extensions $A\subset B\subset \operatorname{Frac}A=\operatorname{Frac} B$, where $A\subset B$ is integral extension, and an element $a\in \operatorname{Frac}A$ integral over $A$, then $a$ is also integral over $B$ so that $a\in B$. This shows $B$ contains eny element $\in \operatorname{Frac}A$ integral over $A$, i.e. contains the integral closure.

Lastly, this is the most usual and common procedure to find the integral clousure of an integral domain as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks so much! This really cleared up all my 'gaps' that I had. Marked as accepted.